# Spring circular dependency - enviorment related issue

Tags: java, spring

**This is not code related issue** - since it does work on other environments.

The problem that I occur is

```
24 maj 2013 10:52:18:762 ERROR [main] [ContextLoader:215] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.my.code.DirectoryManager': Bean with name 'com.my.code.DirectoryManager' has been injected into other beans [com.my.code.CustomerManager,com.my.code.ProjectManager] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
```

The fun fact is that that this same code work on other environments. 
Java version is the same (jdk 1.6.33 x64)
Also there is cglib.jar in classpath.
Enviorment variables are the same. As container I use tomcat 6.0.18.
OS is Centos 5.6 x64
There is free space and free memory. 
I didn't mess up anything with jvm options.

Have anyone of you seen issue like this? What else I can check? Most solved issues (which I was able to fine) are code-related but **this is not code**

Comment: Have you double-checked that all your dependencies are the correct version? Maybe a maven repo issue, or similar for whatever build tool you are using.

Comment: I don't this this is the problem with your code. Can you please check if your deployment (EAR or WAR) on each environment is exactly same ? By this I mean start with size, then modules/jars etc. This could usually happen if you have two profiles creating different type of WAR/EAR (I had been a victim :) )

Comment: WAR's are the same (we use maven to build rpm with tomcat + application) and this rpm is distributed to environments.

Comment: I'd say this is a configuration issue.

What does the Spring app context configuration look like?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue right now. I'm going to post a separate question with my specific information. Mine is a Circular Dependency error and if Jenkins performs the release, it happens. However, if I run the maven release from my laptop(windows), it seems to work without any code changes. Also, if I download the "corrupted" jar that is causing the error and unzip it, then zip it up on my machine the error goes away. Very weird. Also, I will mention that Jenkins is running on linux Centos.